# Does the spectral radius of a matrix define a norm?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-radius

Does the spectral radius of a matrix define a norm? Does it satisfy the properties of norm, i.e.,

1. $\| x \| \ge 0$
2. $\| x \| = 0 \implies x=0$
3. $\| kx \| = |k| \cdot \|x \|$
4. $\| x+y \| \le \|x\| + \|y\|$

Comment: What is the spectral radius of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$? Oh, and for the triangle inequality, try $x=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $y=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$!

Comment: 0, actually I think I see now where this is going, we can find matrices such that the fourth property is not satisfied, hence not a norm

Comment: Yep. I suggest you write it up as an answer and accept it. I am too lazy (it's bedtime in my corner of the world). And we don't like unanswered questions lying around.

Comment: It's not that useless though: the spectral radius is a lower bound for any compatible norm.

Comment: This depends on the dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Choose matrices x and y such that the fourth property (triangle inequality) is not satisfied.  There are plenty of matrices which will show that

$$\rho(A+B) > \rho(A)+\rho(B)$$

Comment: Can you always find such matrices?

Comment: Take $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ and $B=A^T$ then $\rho(A)=\rho(B)=0$ but $\rho(A+B) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

if you choose any nilpotent matrix M so you have existence of $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $M^k=0$ so in $M^n=0$ for all $n\geq k$ and :
$$
\|M^n\|^{1/n}=0 
$$
So $\rho(M)=\lim_n \|M^n\|^{1/n}=0$.
we can conclude that the spectral radius of any nilpotent matrix is equal to $0$.
and so the spectral radius can't be a norme.